# How to find the first unique encounters of a sub string in R

Tags: r, select, substring, unique

Could you please help me with the following R scripting problem:

I would like to select and save the strings which have the first unique value of a substring. 
In this case I would like to know the first strings that have a unique combination of substring H..V.. substring 4 to 9

I would like to find all the unique H and V patterns, such as H22V01, next unique would be H23V01 etc, and then return the first full string per unique substring that belongs to these unique substrings.

## input

```
x <- c("139H22V01",
"129H22V01",
"125H22V01",
"116H22V01",
"168H22V01",
"175H22V01",
"204H22V01",
"258H23V01",
"168H23V01",
"116H23V01",
"129H22V02",
"168H22V02")
```

## expected output:

```
outp <- c( "129H22V01" , "258H23V01" , "129H22V02" )
```

Comment: In your examples there are no unique H..V.. patterns ?

Comment: If I understand right, you need first occurence of each H..V.. ? You should also include expected output from the provided input, and how do you intend to accomplish this, what language, scripts, etc.?

Comment: Can you please explain why you have "129H22V01" and not "139H22V01" in your expected output?

Comment: haha because I overlooked the first string, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
x[!duplicated(substring(x, first = 4))]
# [1] "139H22V01" "258H23V01" "129H22V02"
```